# No consigo recuperar variable de java en struts2

Tags: java, struts

Estoy aprendiendo a usar java con struts en una web dinamica y en la prueba que realizo (el famoso calculo del IMC) logro pasar a la pagina de resultado la clasificación pero no logro obtener el valor del imc, que estaré haciendo mal?

```
    // Metodo para calcular el IMC
    public void calcularIMC() {
        imc = peso / (altura * altura);
    }

    public double getIMC() {
        return imc;
    } 

    // Metodo de clasificaicon segun el IMC
    public String getEstado() {
        calcularIMC();

        String estado = "";
        if (imc < 16.00) {
            estado  = "Infrapeso: Delgadez Severa";
        } else if (imc <= 16.00 || imc <= 16.99) {
            estado = "Infrapeso: Delgadez moderada";
        } else if (imc <= 17.00 || imc <= 18.49) {
            estado = "Infrapeso: Delgadez aceptable";
        } else if (imc <= 18.50 || imc <= 24.99) {
            estado = "Peso Normal";
        } else if (imc <= 25.00 || imc <= 29.99) {
            estado = "Sobrepeso";
        } else if (imc <= 30.00 || imc <= 34.99) {
            estado = "Obeso: Tipo I";
        } else if (imc <= 35.00 || imc <= 39.99) {
            estado = "Obeso: Tipo II";
        } else if (imc > 40.00) { 
            estado = "Obeso: Tipo III";
        }
        return estado;
    }

    public void setEstado(String estado) {
        this.estado = estado;
    }
```

Y esta es mi pagina de resultado, donde si se refleja el valor de estado, en mi caso sobrepeso pero es solo un detalle, pero al pedir la variable imc no me muestra nada, en blanco, intenté llamando directamente al método getIMC() pero me devuelve valor 0, y estoy seguro de que el calculo se realiza ya que el método getIMC() da resultado ya que se utiliza para clasificar el estado, el cual varía si cambio los valores de peso y altura...2

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Valor IMC</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Resultado IMC</h3>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>Valor IMC</td>
            <td><s:property value="imc" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Su estado</td>
            <td><s:property value="estado" /></td>  
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Agradeceré la  iluminación para este pobre aprendiz.

Comment: Muestra como instancias luego la clase y como le pasas los parametros para el calculo del imc

Answer (score 0):

estas trabajando los métodos con atributos de la clase, pero para referirte a atributos de la clase dentro de un metodo debe ser de esta manera:

```java
private int miatributo = 0;

public void setAtributo(int atributo){
   this.miatributo = atributo;
}

public int getAtributo(){
   return this.miatributo;
}
```

¿que te falto? declarar los atributos de la clase y referirte a ellos con .this

Comment: Gracias pero creo que el problema no pasa por eso ya que el calculo del IMC se realiza y se coteja el resultado con los rangos para devolver el "estado". Lo cambié como señalas pero no hay diferencia en el resultado, funciona igual sin poder mostrar el el atributo imc